# Suppressing errors in LoadLibrary

Tags: windows, loadlibrary, error-suppression

I'm trying to get rid of the error messages Windows sometimes pops when loading a DLL.

I tried to do the following:

```
UINT oldErrorMode = SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
SetErrorMode(oldErrorMode | SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);

LoadLibrary(myDll);

SetErrorMode(oldErrorMode);
```

But I'm still getting the error windows, I tried to load several DLLs to make sure they don't remove
the SerErrorMode() so that's not the case.

Does anybody has an idea what else can I try?

Thanks

Comment: What error message does pop up? Can you provide a screenshot or something similar?

Comment: Some thoughts. When you call `LoadLibrary`, the other DLL changes the error mode and removes `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS`. Or perhaps the errors are not from your calls to `LoadLibrary`, but are in fact from implicitly linked DLLs.

Comment: I get stuff like "File SYNSOEMU.DLL could not be located in the Windows system folder" , "Can't find registry record", ....

Comment: David: The setErrorMode should be inherited in the hierarchy unless there's another setErrorMode in between, right?

Comment: Yes, you need to preserve the existing error mode when setting a new error mode, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/27/198410.aspx