# LoadLibrary() : How to handle invalid DLLs?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I have an application that relies heavily on plugins.

On startup it scans a directory for DLLs and loads them one by one, looking for ones that implement a certain exported function. However - if someone were to rename a different type of file to *.dll and put it in the directory, that file would then also be loaded by `LoadLibrary()`. `LoadLibrary()` doesn't like that and produces an error [dialog].

Is there a way to simply ignore invalid / incompatible `.dll` files (either detecting them prior to the call or have `LoadLibrary()` return `NULL` rather than throwing a fit)?

Comment: See [Suppressing errors in LoadLibrary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254122/suppressing-errors-in-loadlibrary)

Comment: I shouldn't worry about it too much; you can't protect the user from every stupid thing they might do.  What if there is a valid DLL whose DllMain function displays a dialog box? Or just crashes?  However, David has a point; since `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS` is the recommended error mode *anyway* you may as well go ahead and use it.  (At least if you are reasonably confident that the existing code has decent error handling!)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the error mode for your process. Do this once and for all at startup:

```
UINT oldMode = SetErrorMode(0);
SetErrorMode(oldMode | SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX);
```

After you've set the process error mode, when `LoadLibrary` fails no dialog box will be displayed and `LoadLibrary` will return `NULL`.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff805117.aspx) says:

> Best practice is that all applications call the process-wide SetErrorMode function with a parameter of SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS at startup. This is to prevent error mode dialogs from hanging the application.

I also recommend adding `SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX` for reasons that I guess should be obvious.

Comment: Hmmm.  What concerns me is that if the app doesn't *have* proper error handling code, which is common enough, heaven knows, then this change could easily make things worse rather than better.  Unless you're able to audit the entire codebase, it may be better not to mess with the error mode.  On the other hand, it seems that the default setting is inherited from the parent process (!) so you're sunk either way, at least potentially.  So, yeah, you're probably right.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> Remarks
>
> To enable or disable error messages displayed by the loader during DLL loads, use the SetErrorMode function.

Don't forget to restore the error mode after you are finished.

If you wanted to do this yourself, in a primitive manner you could parse the PE header to identify obvious cases of bad DLL files, however it is not really possible to determine if a DLL is valid and loadable without a full PE loader which requires a lot of work and is already built into the operating system.

Comment: yeah, you can use `GetBinaryType` for EXEs, but it won't work with DLLs.  Really, it's got to look at the header anyway, so why can't it just set *lpBinaryType* to some DLL-type identifier?  Sigh.

Comment: Well you can load the file yourself, then just inspect the PE header. You are basically looking for 'MZ' then some other bits. But validation that it is not just a file pretending to be a DLL is much more complex than this alone.

Comment: Obviously, you can load the file yourself and check to see if it's a valid PE (and, if you intend to load it as a DLL, that it is valid for your application architecture to use).  It would just be a stupid thing to do in most cases.  My point was that MS already provides a quick check for binary type, so any reason for them to *not* have it support the same functionality for DLLs (it's *already* there) in that same function is kind of a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer after feedback in comments from  djgandy and Remy Lebeau.  Now a complete
function, better preservation of error mode at entry:

```
// This function will load the DLL named by pszPath if it is a valid library.
// If the function succeeds, it will return a valid HMODULE for the DLL.  This
// handle should be passed to FreeLibrary when it is no longer needed.
// If the function fails, it will return NULL and no annoying dialog boxes will 
// be displayed.  It is therefore up to the caller to notify the user about what 
// happened or take any other appropriate action.  The reason for failure can
// be obtained from GetLastError().  Common problems:
//   ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT        - Bad DLL (tested function with text file)
//   ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND         - Missing DLL (tested with file that did not exist)
// 
// Module-loading functions can return several other errors, look at winerror.h
// list starting at ERROR_INVALID_MODULETYPE
//
// Obviously, since it's just a wrapper around LoadLibrary this function is not
// safe to call from DllMain.
//
// NB: GetErrorMode() is only available on Vista / Server 2003 or later.
HMODULE LoadLibraryIfValid(LPCTSTR pszPath)
{
  HMODULE hModule = NULL;

    UINT prevErrorMode = GetErrorMode();
    SetErrorMode(prevErrorMode | SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
    hModule = LoadLibrary(pszPath);
    SetErrorMode(prevErrorMode);

  return hModule;
}
```

If targeting Windows 7 / Server 2008 R2 or later, the Get/SetThreadErrorMode()
functions are available, but might not be worth it or even a good alternative
(discussion in comments, below)

If anyone cared enough to put the time into it (I sure don't), a version of 
this function could easily be written using GetModuleHandle for kernel32 and 
GetProcAddress to be compatible with earlier versions of Windows as well as 
provide a global/per-thread error mode option for platforms that support it 
(truly pointless because it's only changed for the duration of one call anyway).

This is the largest commentary-to-code ratio in my life.

Comment: I'd say not to use SetErrorMode either. The SetErrorMode page says to use SetThreadErrorMode if targetting Win7 and above.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd553630(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The SetThreadErrorMode page says: "Best practice is that all applications call the process-wide SetErrorMode function with a parameter of SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS at startup."  The Win7 recommendation on that page to "favor" the thread-specific version is specifically because "it is less disruptive to the normal behavior of the system" but since it's getting set right back it doesn't matter.  Also, SetThreadErrorMode *may* have an issue under Windows 10 - see comments in your linked page (not personally verified by me because I don't care that much).

Comment: I saw that. I assumed that was if you just wanted to disable error dialogs entirely for your application forever, not temporarily. It says its a best practice. It has the same comment on SetErrorMode page too. Sounds like they are saying this is something all applications should just do...

Comment: @djgandy: "Sounds like they are saying..." Sometimes, trying to decipher what MS is saying, what they mean, and what your code *will actually do* based on those things is like trying to figure out what my wife is thinking.

Comment: hah indeed. Try writing a display driver using their WDDM documentation. D3DKMT_FLIPMODEL_PRESENTHISTORYTOKEN is my favourite for sentences of documentation that describe the name of the variable, or reserved. Not helpful :-(

Comment: When using `SetErrorMode()`, you need to preserve the existing error mode, otherwise nested error modes will not work correctly, see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/27/198410.aspx

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: really? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679355(v=vs.85).aspx  My comment on this starts with"NB:".

Comment: The MS recommendations are clear enough. Error mode only exists as a compat mechanism. Apps should not be running without suppressing error dialogs. It's really simple. Do what msdn says. Suppress them at startup and that's it. All this pfaffinf around changing error modes and then restoring them is crazy talk. Sane apps don't do that.

Comment: @frasnian: "since it's being set right back it doesn't matter" ... not true, another thread might load a library before you reverse the change.